# SOAP UI - "Error getting response"

Tags: soapui

I am trying to use SOAP UI by connecting to my organization's VPN from home. But I am getting this error -

*"Error getting response: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to 
https ://xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx:xxxx refused"*

How can I get rid of this error ? 
Does it has to do something with the SOAP UI settings?

Edit - Below is the error.log file

```
Wed May 01 13:57:00 *** 2013:ERROR:org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://stage2cpplvs52.qa.paypal.com:7021 refused
   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://stage2cpplvs52.qa.paypal.com:7021 refused
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:561)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:236)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:345)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:241)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:299)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: please check the soapui log file and error.log file for more info and post it here.  Could only really guess from what you have posted here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Go to file > Preferences >Proxy settings and set Proxy to :None
```

Just try like this

Comment: I did that, nothing changed, but my issue is not VPN-related.

Answer (score 2):

This issue in corporate sectors is due to "Environment & Port Access not provided to your User ID".

So contact the Corporate Network service team and request for access to the folder.

How to notice this issue?

Go to command prompt,

enter the following command,

ping "endpoint url"

press enter.

if you are not getting any response, that means u dont have access to that URL(Call your system administrator and request access to that URL).

if you got response,

then in command prompt enter following command,

telnet "endpoint URL" "port number"

press enter.

if you didn't get response, it means you don't have permission to access the port of that specific "endpoint url". So request your system administrator to provide access to that url and the specific port

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure or shutdown proxyserver in preferences or check your firewall settings.

Answer (score 0):

this happens when the server you are trying to connect is down or the service that you are trying to access is not started.

in your case, looks like server 'stage2cpplvs52.qa.paypal.com' is down or having some problems while starting it.

try restarting/starting server and access service from browser first before you connect it from SOAP UI.

Answer (score 0):

Solution here: https://yiingw.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/soapui-5-0-0-org-apache-http-nohttpresponseexception-the-target-server-failed-to-respond/

Enable “Expect-Continue” and everything goes fine now.

File→HTTP Settings→Expect-Continue: Adds Expect-Continue header to outgoing request

Reference:
http://www.soapui.org/Working-with-soapUI/preferences.html
rfc 2616

Answer (score 0):

For me what helped was changing my application's hosting model to Out Of Process.
Go to application properties->Debug->Hosting Model->Out Of Process